# Can't Find Excel Source Data

Tags: excel, charts

I'm putting together a sheet for someone who is out of the office, and trying to refresh their charts. The source data all refers to cells that look like "Data!$E:$4", for example, but I can't find these "Data" cells. There is no tab called "Data" that is hidden, or anything like that. [Here is an image of what the edit data menu looks like when I'm looking at the chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTV6H.png)

When I type in "=Data!$E$4 into a random cell, it actually pulls the reference that the chart was referring to, but I still can't find the data. When I trace precedents, it looks like this:[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEzWR.png)

I've also tried to "show data in hidden rows and columns" in the chart menu, and it doesn't reveal anything. I feel like the data is hidden within the chart, but I can't find it, and I've never seen a chart that is built that way. Has anyone had any experience with this kind of thing, and know where I might be able to find the data, so that I can update it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Perhaps not the data but the tab is hidden.  Right click on a tab beneath, and look for show "show hidden tab".

Comment: That was the first thing I looked for, there unfortunately aren't any hidden tabs, though!

Comment: Perhaps it has been veryhidden in code. Check in the VB editor - look at the project explorer.

Comment: @rory, no Macros/VB either! :(

Comment: Did you check the list of tabs in the vb editor? a+f11, then look at the list of tabs in that worksheet on the left. Make sure none are very hidden

Comment: While it is possible to hard code data within charts I don't thinks it's the case based on your screenshots. Have you checked for "very hidden" sheets? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/12/20/very-hidden-sheets-excel/